# JAVA prefixing all the elements of an xml

Tags: java, xml, namespaces

Is there any way I can prefix each element of my xml in java? For example, I have the following xml:

```xml
    <node1 xmlns="www.test.com">
       <node2>abc</node2>
       <node3>
           <node3_1>test1</node3_1>
       </node3>
     </node1>
```

I want to convert it to:

```xml
    <test:node1 xmlns test="www.test.com">
       <test:node2>abc</test:node2>
       <test:node3>
           <test:node3_1>test1</test:node3_1>
       </test:node3>
     </test:node1>
```

Is there an easy way to do this? So far I have tried:

```
 String messageString = message.getPayloadAsString();
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
 DocumentBuilder builder;  
 Document document = null;
 try  
    {  
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
        document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( messageString) ) );  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 

    XmlObject inboundMessageObject = XmlObject.Factory.parse(document);
    XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions(); 
    Map<String, String> namespaceMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    namespaceMap.put("www.test.com", "test");
    xmlOptions.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes(namespaceMap);

            xmlObject.save(System.out, xmlOptions); 

    String prefixedXML = inboundMessageObject.xmlText(xmlOptions);
    return prefixedXML;
```

What I see is, the prefixedXML String is the same as the messageString string.

Comment: Why would you want to do this when the default `xmlns` is already specified ? Adding a prefix does nothing in the 2nd example.

Comment: I need to do this because of a stupid issue our server is having when I send the xml in the first way. So far, I tried this:

XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions(); 

//key = uri, value = prefix 
Map<String, String> namespaceMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
namespaceMap.put("www.test.com", "test"); 
xmlOptons.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes(namespaceMap); 

xmlObject.save(System.out, xmlOptions);

Comment: In the future, please add substantial comments like that to your question (as I have done for you). Can you explain whether your current code works?

Comment: Do you have an XSD for this document?

Comment: For the sake of completion could you also elaborate on this issue ? I'm still lost as to why a default NS wont do.

Comment: @Duncan Jones: sorry for the bad format. I edited my question again to give a clear picture of what I am doing. Yes. I do have an xsd.

Comment: @Deepak Bala: I am really not sure why the default namespace is not working. my guess is that jaxws is screwing the document up when I put in a default namespace. But I am not sure. I was told to send every element with a namespace prefix.

Comment: Is this structure from an XSD in a WSDL ? Was the `elementFormQualified` correctly set when you generated the service ?

Comment: sorry... corrected the xml. it was a copy paste error. But still, the code does not work.

Comment: @Deepak Bala: I don't have access to the service code to figure it out. I was asked to send each element with a namespace prefix and thats what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
xml = xml.replaceFirst("xmlns=", "xmlns:test=").replaceAll("<(/?)", "<$1test:");
```

Comment: Not a fan of this solution. It wouldn't work well in more elaborate cases where the XML contains multiple namespaces.

Comment: this works, but the problem is that if the xml is already prefixed or if some tags are prefixed already, this fails...